# Add a different element to ArrayAdapter/ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView that's being populated by an ArrayAdapter:

`someListView.setAdapter(adapter);`

Each element in the adapter is inflated using the same layout.xml. Now I want to add an element of a different type (inflated using a different layout file) to the beginning of the ListView.

What I want to achieve is, to have a special element on top of all other elements in the list view, but also scrolls with the list (exits the screen from top if the user scrolls down).

I've tried to add the new element to the array but it's a different type so that won't work.

I've tried to insert a dummy element to the array at position 0, and modify the adapter's `getView()` so that `if (position == 0) return myUniqueView`, but that screwed up the entire list view somehow: items not showing, stuff jumping all over the place, huge gaps between elements, etc.

I start to think the best practice of achieving what I want, is not through editing the array adapter. But I don't know how to do it properly.

Comment: inflate again for position 0 before returning it. or post ur complete adpter code to write soln 4 u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need anything special to do what you ask.  Android already provides that behavior built in to every ListView.  Just call:

```
mListView.addHeaderView(viewToAdd);
```

That's it.

[ListView Headers API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29)
[Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#miscellaneous_headerfooter)

Comment: That's so true! Just make sure to call `addHeaderView()` before `setAdapter()` and I'm all set! It scrolls and everything! Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter add a check on the position

```
private static final int LAYOUT_CONFIG_HEADER = 0;
private static final int LAYOUT_CONFIG_ITEMS = 1;   

int layoutType;

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if (position== 0){
        layoutType = LAYOUT_CONFIG_HEADER;
    } else {
        layoutType = LAYOUT_CONFIG_ITEMS;
    }
    return layoutType;
}


@Override  
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View row = convertView;
LayoutInflater inflater = null;
int layoutType = getItemViewType(position);
   if (row  == null) {
    if (layoutType == LAYOUT_CONFIG_HEADER) {
      //inflate layout header
      }
    }  else {
      //inflate layout of others rows
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I said in the original post, I have already tried this.

Comment: add your attempt or your adapter so we can be more detailed

Comment: Messing with position numbers like this is very dangerous. You're literally breaking many assumptions taken internally by the ArrayAdapter. Can you make it work...yes, but you'll need to overload many other methods to ensure adding, removing, retrieving items account for a position offset.  Hence why it probably didn't work for user1032613

Comment: override `getItemViewType` and `getView` is enough

Answer (score 0):

Do't know exactly but it might usefull

https://github.com/chrisjenx/ParallaxScrollView